# Not giving results for posts

Tags: wordpress, search

I am running a website which is using WPML with Wordpress. Hebrew is the default language and it also has English. When I do a search in Hebrew (the default language), I am given search results for my query. However, when I switch languages in the search page, the results seem to disappear. I have installed the plugin "Search Everything" which I have customized to search every custom field.

Is WPML blocking search results from being shown when the language switches? 
Is it possible to stop WPML from giving results for Posts?

I have provided the two search result pages below.

http://www.cleanupisrael.org.il/?x=0&y=0&s=Beach&x=0&y=0

http://www.cleanupisrael.org.il/?lang=en&s=Beach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably why it's happening:

> When the searchform ID is set for the form and the lang input exists, WPML limits the search to that language...(1)

See, in the search form on the webpage you gave earlier, there is a line like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lang" id="lang" value="en">
```

If you take out that "*lang*" hidden form input, it might fix your problem.

Reference:

1. http://wpml.org/documentation/support/creating-multilingual-wordpress-themes/search-form/

Comment: If that doesn't work, the reference article also mentions something about using the ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE like this:  `<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="<?php echo(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE); ?>"/>`

But, I don't know if that is the functionality that you want, here.